# Creating a custom transform in Jest

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, testing, jestjs

I'm trying to create a custom transform for Jest, but running into a documentation roadblock which has me asking myself if I'm even on the right track.

**Problem**

I have a Rails project which is serving a Vue JS app. I want to write Jest tests for the JS app. In order to pass config variables from Rails to the app, I'm using ERB to template a small number of `.js` files. For example:

```
// in server-routes.js.erb
export default {
  reports: '<%= Rails.application.config.relative_url_root %><%= Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.reports_path %>',
  ...
```

In my Webpack build for the Vue app, I use `rails-erb-loader` to preprocess the `*.erb` files before they get passed to the rest of the build process.

However, when I run my JS tests, Jest doesn't know anything about ERB loaders (reasonably enough). So my goal is to add a custom transform for Jest to convert the ERB files when running `npm test`.

**Approach**

I thought I might be able to use `rails-erb-loader` as a Jest transform:

```
// package.json
"jest": {
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "js",
    "json",
    "vue"
  ],
  "moduleDirectories": [
    "<rootDir>/node_modules"
  ],
  "transform": {
    ".*\\.(vue)$": "vue-jest",
    "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
    "^.+\\.js\\.erb$": "rails-erb-loader"
  },
```

This doesn't work, however, because Jest transforms and Webpack loaders seemingly have different signatures. In particular, Jest expects a `process` function:

```
$ npm test
 FAIL  app/javascript/components/__tests__/dummy.test.js
 ● Test suite failed to run
TypeError: Jest: a transform must export a `process` function.

> 101 | import ServerRoutes from '../server-routes.js.erb';
      | ^

  at ScriptTransformer._getTransformer (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:291:15)
  at ScriptTransformer.transformSource (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:353:28)
  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:457:40)
  at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:513:25)
  at app/javascript/components/related-media.vue:101:1
  at Object.<anonymous> (app/javascript/components/related-media.vue:232:3)
```

And this is where I get stuck, because I can't see where it's documented what the API and behaviour of a `process` function should be. In the [documentation for the `transform` config option](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#transform-object-string-string) there's a single [not very helpful example](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/webpack), and that's it as far as docs go, unless I've missed something.

I also note that `babel-jest` has a `createTransformer` function which sounds like it might be helpful, or at least illuminating, but again I can't find any docs on what it does.

If anyone has pointers on the details of creating custom Jest transforms, or at least some better docs, that would be great! Or, if I'm going about this the wrong way, what should I be doing?

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: did you find a solution? someone did this: https://github.com/cpcwood/jest-erb-transformer

Answer (score 2):

You could look at ts-jest. https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/blob/master/src/ts-jest-transformer.ts.  It is in typescript so is typed

Alternatively find the jest code that initiates the transform process.  I don't think it is that difficult to find.

I think the transformer is either created with class constructor or via the factory function createTransformer.

Comment: It is a good idea to dive in already existing transformers.

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding for the [ts-jest-transformer](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/blob/master/src/ts-jest-transformer.ts) and [jest-erb-transformer](https://github.com/cpcwood/jest-erb-transformer) it seems you need to export an object with public `process` or to export `createTransformer` methods which create a transformer object that have a `process` method.

a simple code example that runs before ts-jest

transform-example.js

```js
const tsJest = require('ts-jest');
const t = tsJest.createTransformer();

module.exports = {
   process(fileContent, filePath, jestConfig) {
      const res = t.process(fileContent, filePath, jestConfig)
      console.log(filePath);
      return res;
   }
 }
```

jest.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
   transform: {
      '^.+\\.tsx?$': ['<rootDir>/transform-example']
   }
}
```

running this would run typescript tests (just like ts-jest) and log all the file paths transformed in the test.